# Extract the first part of a string before a double backslash in bash

Tags: awk, sed, backslash

I would like to get the substring before "\". My example is as follows:

from

```
-3\\0.3748
```

I would like to extract `-3`.

Comment: Then use `${variable%%\\*}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on the `\`:

```
$ echo '-3\\0.3748' | awk -F '\\' '{print $1}'
-3
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but since I see you and @rid were wondering why your answers got downvoted - since this forum exists to help people with their code, whenever a question is posted without code it's off topic and so usually downvoted and/or closed. When anyone answers such a question their answer can often also get downvoted to discourage people from accepting/encouraging such questions. So post an answer to a question without code if you like but don't be shocked if it gets downvoted.

Comment: The other thing that will cause answers to get downvotes is not having enough of an explanation for the code. I personally think that's absurd as often small snippets of code don't need any explanation and people who don't understand it will benefit more from reading the man page than a trivial explanation but there are people who as soon as they see that jump on it and downvote, especially if the automated tool flags it as possibly low quality for that reason. So those are the 2 most likely reasons why your and @rid's answers received downvotes.